# Is there any way to shorten this machine code Hello World in AArch64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, optimization, arm64, code-size

I am working on a compiled AArch64 assembly file of a "Hello World" program for Linux.

I have already successfully shortened it from 504 bytes down to 124 bytes.The only more "optimization" I can think of would be to find some instructions that perform two or more tasks in single instruction.

Currently the machine code in the file (represented in asm) is this:

```
  mov x8, 64     // __NR_write
  adr x1, hello  //the string, I know the exact address
  mov x2, 10     //string length (actually only "HelloWorld")

j:
  mov x0, 0      // write to stdin happens to work
  svc 0
  mov x8, 93     // __NR_exit
  b j    //the branching saves me one instruction to exit with status = 0
```

Is there any instruction to shorten anything here?

Comment: This is for Linux, right?  Building into an ELF executable?  Are you packing this code into the ELF header or something, like in https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html?

Comment: Yes, there are many overlappings and writing into headers

Comment: Some future readers would probably appreciate it if you at least link the full source, with a build command.

Comment: Well, I am not building it, I am writing raw bytes into file from a manually created hexdump

Comment: That sounds inconvenient vs. building it with `as` (from source including some `.byte` and `.word` directives) and using `objcopy` to get the .text section into a file by itself.  Like that x86 tutorial / article is doing with NASM, which can assemble into a flat binary directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work to `ldp x0, x2, [sp], #16` to pop the top two words from the stack, `argc` and `argv[0]`, into x0 and x2, if you don't mind writing a bunch of binary `\0` bytes (or even other garbage) after your string.

The Linux process startup environment has the stack pointer pointing at `argc`, and above that the `argv[]` array values.  (Not a *pointer* to argv like `main` gets; the first double-word of it is `argv[0]`.  Above `argv[]` is `env[]`.)

- `argc` will be 1, so that works for stdout fd, if run normally from a shell with no args.
- `argv` is a pointer to stack memory, so is a huge integer much larger than 10, so `write()` will read bytes until it hits an unmapped page.
  (Linux `write` does actually copy preceding bytes to the fd, not returning `-EFAULT` if a non-zero amount of bytes can be written before hitting a fault.  It seems it only checks the readability of later pages when it gets to them.
  This is an implementation detail that isn't documented, but is what current Linux actually does, at least on x86-64.)

This might even still exit with 0 status, assuming it's run with no args.  Post-increment addressing will make the `ldp` next iteration load x0 = `argv[1]` = NULL. (And `env[0]` into x2; we know we won't segfault from reading past the top of the stack region because env[] is up there.)

But it's not necessary to `exit(0)` to get text printed; any exit status can work.  (If you don't mind the noise from the shell, you could even arrange your program so it segfaults instead of making an exit system call, saving all the instructions after the first `svc 0`!)

---

If you ran the program with no args via a manual execve, so `argv[0] = 0`, it would call `write(0, hello, 0)` and thus wouldn't print anything.

But if you ran it with one arg (not counting argv[0] that shells pass implicitly), it would print to stderr.  With 2 or more args, it would try to write to a not-open fd and write would return `-EBADF`, as you could see under `strace`.

Comment: the idea is good, but, 1) I am storing the string in the file header and there is not space for any more bytes, 2) I must exit with status code 0, that was condition, I specified for myself

Comment: @gXLg: Ah, then you'd be stuck with trailing garbage, unless you can have it in a segment whose FILESZ ends at the end of the string, so the rest of the page is filled with zeros like the BSS is.  But presumably you only have one entry in your ELF program header that covers that and the executable code, and another entry would increase the total size.

Comment: Yes, I am, only one program header, no section headers, and 16 bytes overlapping between program and file header. Still thank you for the time, you put into it.